# Angular 4 - How to add a material design HTML element into a file with Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, material-design, angular-material2

I'm attempting to insert a md-button-toggle into a button toggle group programatically with Angular but [Create Element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) doesn't seem to work well with non standard HTML tags.

**HTML snippet i'm attempting to append:**

```
        <md-button-toggle-group class="toggle-box" [vertical]="true" id="button-toggle-group">
            <dash-theme (onSelected)="setTheme($event);sidenav.close()"></dash-theme>
            <md-button-toggle routerLink="/admin/dashboard" (click)=sidenav.close()>
                Admin Dashboard
            </md-button-toggle>
        </md-button-toggle-group>
```

**Angular attempt:**

```
// adds a View Dashboard button to the side nav bar when 
addViewDashboard(): void {
    var node = document.createElement('<md-button-toggle routerLink="/' + this.dashboardName
        + '" (click)=sidenav.close() id="view-dashboard-button"> View Dashboard </md-button-toggle>');
    document.getElementById("button-toggle-group").appendChild(node);
    }
```

(this.dashboardName is just a string which will be passed into the router)

I realize CreateElement isn't supposed to work like this and can't really think of how else I can manage to do this.

**The end product should be something like:**

```
        <md-button-toggle-group class="toggle-box" [vertical]="true" id="button-toggle-group">
            <dash-theme (onSelected)="setTheme($event);sidenav.close()"></dash-theme>
            <md-button-toggle routerLink="/admin/dashboard" (click)=sidenav.close()>
                Admin Dashboard
            </md-button-toggle>
            <md-button-toggle routerLink="/[this.dashboardName Value]" (click)=sidenav.close() id="view-dashboard-button">
                View Dashboard
            </md-button-toggle>
        </md-button-toggle-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use an array to represent the button toggle info...

```
<md-button-toggle-group class="toggle-box" [vertical]="true" id="button-toggle-group">
    <dash-theme (onSelected)="setTheme($event);sidenav.close()"></dash-theme>
    <md-button-toggle *ngFor="let b of buttons" routerLink="b.route" (click)="b.clickAction()">{{b.title}}</md-button-toggle>
</md-button-toggle-group>
```

Here's an example of the component property you can use to drive the template.

```
buttons: any = [
    { title: 'button 1', route: '/admin/dashboard', clickAction: () => { alert('action 1'); } },
    { title: 'button 2', route: '/[this.dashboardName Value]', clickAction: () => { alert('action 2'); } }
]
```